# Can not search by typing any part of the name from table using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot filter data from table by typing any part of the name inside the search field using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="letter">
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Restaurant Name</th>
</tr>
<tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | startsWithLetter:letter | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
 <td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here I am filtering the `restaurant name` by typing the name inside the input field. My controller side code is given below.

```
customerView.filter('startsWithLetter', function () {
    return function (items, search) {
        //console.log('items',items);
        if(items != undefined){
            if (!search) {
            return items;
          }
          search = search.toLowerCase();
          return items.filter(function(element) {
            return element.rest_name.toLowerCase().substring(0, search.length).indexOf(search) != -1;
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Suppose I have a restaurant name `the Joyce on 4th Irish pub`. Now if I am typing each letter from the beginning of the restaurant then the it's filtering from the table. But suppose I am typing any part of this name like `Joyce`  then it should filter and display in the table.

Comment: If I understood your code correctly you only compare to a substring of the length of your search word which would explain why it only searches from the start (also the filter name 'startsWithLetter' would rather indicate that behaviour)

Comment: But here i need if user is searching any part of the name ,then related restaurant name should fillter. Can you please share your answer ?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with your example so I can test my solution? (It should be enough to just remove the `.substring(0, search.length)` part)

Comment: Ok,Let me to make the plunkr example.

Comment: Actually [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sYvOKuXm4hlMgeu5ys6O?p=preview) my plunkr it has some syntax error but the issue is coming in my originally code.

Comment: The idea of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that others can test their solutions on your problem to see if their answer works. Thus a not working plunkr does not really help. I fixed it now (you forgot `angular.module('app' >, [] <)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments the solution is to remove the `.substring(0, search.length` part since that only takes the first x (length of search word) characters of your entry and searches your search term inside that part.

Without that you search the entered word in the whole string.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/8n0vzma1/) for a working demo.